# Density operator of a system $S$ coupled to a bath $B$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

In the second equation of section 8.1 in this  [MIT OCW lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-51-quantum-theory-of-radiation-interactions-fall-2012/lecture-notes/), I can't understand how they went from

$$\rho_{S}(t)=Tr_{B}\{\rho_{SB}(t)\}=\sum_{k}\langle k|U_{SB}(\rho_{S}(0)\otimes|0\rangle\langle 0|_{B})U^{+}_{SB}|k\rangle$$ to

$$\rho_{S}(t)=\sum_{k}\langle k|U_{SB}|0\rangle \rho_{S}(0)\langle 0|U^{+}_{SB}|k\rangle$$

I do understand that there is some kind of rearrangement of the terms, but how do we know that it is a valid rearrangement?

Comment: $\sum_{k}$ denotes a sum over the basis in $\mathcal{H}_B$. The operator $\rho_S$ has nontrivial components only belonging in the $\mathcal{H}_S$ space. So with respect to the  $\mathcal{H}_B$ it is a simply unit operator and can be moved out of product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's express the identity operator on $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_S \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ in the following way

$$\mathbb{I}_{SB}= \mathbb{I}_S\otimes\mathbb{I}_B= \mathbb{I}_S\otimes\sum_l |l\rangle \langle l|.  $$

Let's insert the identity between the time evolution operator and the full density matrix

$$\sum_{k}\langle k|U_{SB}(\rho_{S}(0)\otimes|0\rangle\langle 0|_{B})U^{+}_{SB}|k\rangle= \sum_{k}\langle k|U_{SB} \mathbb{I}_{SB}(\rho_{S}(0)\otimes|0\rangle\langle 0|_{B}) \mathbb{I}_{SB} U^{+}_{SB}|k\rangle\\
=\sum_{k,l,m}\langle k|U_{SB}( \mathbb{I}_{S}\otimes|l\rangle\langle l | )(\rho_{S}(0)\otimes|0\rangle\langle 0|_{B}) ( \mathbb{I}_{S}\otimes|m\rangle\langle m | ) U^{+}_{SB}|k\rangle.$$

Here each operator acts on its respective Hilbert space so this vanishes for all $m,l \neq 0$ so we're left with the traced out time evolution operators on each side of the reduced density matrix.

$$\sum_{k}\langle k|U_{SB}( \mathbb{I}_{S}\otimes|0 \rangle )(\rho_{S}(0)) ( \mathbb{I}_{S}\otimes\langle 0 | ) U^{+}_{SB}|k\rangle\\
=\sum_{k}\langle k|U_{SB}|0 \rangle \rho_{S}(0) \langle 0 |  U^{+}_{SB}|k\rangle,$$
where the operators $\sum_k \langle k | U_{SB}|0\rangle$ and $\sum_k \langle 0 | U_{SB}^{\dagger}|k\rangle$ are defined on $\mathcal{H}_S$.

EDIT: This is precisely what user @spiridon_the_sun_rotator said in their comment, I have just tried to make it slightly more explicit by putting an identity operator there...